# how to render a template inside a template?

Tags: 7

I have entity Car which has a node reference of another entity: Review

Car has a custom .tpl file `node--car.tpl.php` and reviews have there own .tpl files "node--reviews.tpl.php"

when i try to render the reviews of the Car inside the `node--car.tpl.php` the reviews does not render using their own .tpl files,

i am using `render()` drupal function

can someone explain me why?

EDIT:

Heres the code which fetches the reviews:

```
function mymodule_get_reviews( $nid, $full = false ) {
    $field = 'field_car_reference';
    $sql_query = 'SELECT DISTINCT entity_id AS reference FROM {field_data_' . $field . '} WHERE ' . $field . '_nid IS NOT NULL 
        AND ' . $field . '_nid = ' . $nid;

        $queryObj = db_query( $sql_query );

        $type = 'review';
        $nodes = node_load_multiple($queryObj->fetchCol('reference'));

    $reviews = array();

        if( !empty( $nodes ) )
        {       
            foreach( $nodes as $nid => $node_review )
            {
                    if( $node_review->workbench_moderation['current']->state == 'published' ) {
                        $node_review = node_show( $node_review );                                                 
                        $reviews[] = $node_review;
                    }
            }
        }        
    return $reviews;
}
```

the function is called as:

```
$reviews = mymodule_get_reviews( $node->nid );
if( !empty( $reviews ) ) {
  echo render( $reviews ); 
}
```

Comment: Please add the exact code that's causing the problem; the answer will almost certainly be that the templates in question have already been rendered into the array via the theme system, so they won't be run back through a second time when you call `render()`

Comment: hi i have updated the question, please check

Comment: Have you ensured the template is named correctly. Also, perhaps the reviews tpl file is only triggered on certain view modes? The node_show function calls node_view_multiple(), which uses 'teaser' as the default view mode. Is that what you want?

Comment: @jazzdrive3 problem has been fixed already, its just that i was not naming the file correctly.

Answer (score 0):

When a template is not being applied, the first thing to always check for is the filename of the template :)

Make sure it matches the machine name of the content type.